# 2016 Advent of Code Day 2, Part 1 and Part 2

Tags: c, programming-challenge

Continuing from yesterday, here's a simple solution in C to part 1 of [Advent of Code Day 2](http://adventofcode.com/2016/day/2).

I used a simple state machine to map from each keypad key to the next keypad key given the input.

```
// http://adventofcode.com/2016/day/2
//
// "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat" to setup
// cl day01.c to compile
// day01.exe to run

// given a string to be read as moves on a telephone keypad
// identify the code for the bathroom at Easter Bunny HQ section
// starting from the '5'
// 1 2 3
// 4 5 6
// 7 8 9

char * input = "DLDRDDDLULDRRLUDDLDUURDRDUULDRDDRRLDLLUUDDLLRLRDRUURLUDURDDRURLUDDUULUURLLRRRRUDULUDLULLUURRLLRRURRUDUUURRLUUUDURDLLLDULDRLRDDDUDDUURLRRRURULLUDDUULDRRRDDLRLUDDRRDLRDURLRURUDDUULDDUUDDURRLUURRULRRLDLULLRLRUULDUDDLLLRDDULRUDURRDUUDUUDDUULULURDLUDRURDLUUDRDUURDDDRDRLDLDRURRLLRURURLLULLRRUULRRRRDLDULDDLRRRULRURRDURUDUUULDUUDRLDDLDUDDRULLUDUULRRRDRRDRDULDLURDDURLRUDLURLUDDDRLLURUUUUUUURUULDUUDDRLULRUDURRDLDUULLRLULLURDDDDDLRRDLRLLDDUDRRRDDURDLRRUDDUDLRRRDDURULRURRRLDRDUDLD LRRDUDUUUDRRURRDUUULULUDDLLDRRRUDDUULRRDRUDRLLRLRULRRDUUDRLDURUDLLLDRRDLRLUUDRUDRRRUDRRRULDRRLLRDDDLLRDDRULRLLRUDRLLLULDLDDRDRUUUUUULURLLRUDRDRLLULLRUUURRDRULULUDLDURRUUDURLLUDRDLDDULUDLRDDRLRLURULDRURRRRURRDDUDRULUUUDDDRULRULDLLURUUULRDDLRUURLRLDLUULLURDRDDDUDDDRLDRDLLDRDDDDURLUUULDDRURULUDDURDRDRLULDULURDUURDRLLUUUULRULUUDRLLDDRRURUURLDLLRRRDLRURDDLDLDRLRRDLDURULDDLULRRRUUDLRDUURDURLURDDLDLRURLLLDRDULDDRUDDULDDRRLDLRDRDLDUUDLUULRLUDUUDUUUULDURULRRUDULURLRLDRLULLLDUDLLLRUDURDDDURLDDLRLRRDLUDLDDDDLULDRLDUUULDRRDDLRUULDLULUUURUDDRLDDDULRUDRURUURUUURRULRURDURLLRLLUULUULURDRLLUDDLU LLDURDUDRLURUDRLRLUDDRRURDULULDDUDUULRRLRLRRDRDRDURRLRLURRLRUDULLUULLURUDDRLDDDRURLUUDLDURRDURDDLUULRDURRUUURLRRURRDRDRDURRRLULLDRUDLRUDURDRDDLLULLULRRUDULDDRDRRDLLLDLURLRDRDLUDDRLDDLDRULDURLLRLDRDLUDDDDLDUUDRLLRRRRLDDRRLRLURLLRLLUULLDUUDLRDRRRDRDLLDULLDRLDDUDRDDRURRDDLRDLRRUUDRRRRDURUULDRDDURLURRRRURRDRRULULURULUUUDRRRLDLLLDDRULRUDDURDRLDDRDLULLLRURUDRLRDDLDLRRRUURDURLDURRUUDDLRDRUUUURDLRLULRUUDRLDLULLULUURURDULUDUDRRRLLRLURLLDLRRURURRUDLUDDDDRDUDUDUUUULLDRDLLLLUUUUDRLRLUDURLLUDRUUDLLURUULDDDDULUUURLLDL DLULLRDLRRLLLDLRRURRDRURDRUUULDDRLURURRDLRRULUUDDRLRRLDULRRUUDUULDDDUDLLDLURDRLLULLUUULLDURDRRRDDLRDUDRRRLRLDRRLRLULDDUDURRRLDLRULDULDDUDDRULDLDRDRDDRUDRUDURRRRUUDUDRLDURLDLRRUURRDDUDLLDUDRRURRLRRRRRLDUDDRLLLURUDRRUDRLRDUDUUUUUDURULLDUUDLRUUULDUUURURLUUDULDURUDDDLRRRDDRRDLRULLLRDDRLRLUULDUUULLLLDLRURLRRDURRLDLLLDURDLLUDDDLLDDURDDULURDRRRDDDLDDURRULUUDDLULLURULUULDLDDLUDRURURULUDDULRDRLDRRRUUUURUULDRLRRURRLULULURLLDRLRLURULRDDDULRDDLUR RURRULLRRDLDUDDRRULUDLURLRRDDRDULLLUUDDDRDDRRULLLDRLRUULRRUDLDLLLRLLULDRLDDDLLDDULLDRLULUUUURRRLLDRLDLDLDDLUDULRDDLLRLLLULLUDDRDDUUUUDLDLRRDDRDLUDURRUURUURDULLLLLULRRLDRLRDLUURDUUDLDRURURLLDRRRLLLLRDLDURRLRRLLRUUDDUULLRLUDLRRRRRURUDDURULURRUULRDDULUUDUUDDRDDDDDUUUDDDRRLDDRRDDUUULDURLDULURDRDLLURDULRUDRUULUULLRRRRLRUUDDUDLDURURLRRRULRDRRUDDRDDRLRRRLRURRRUULULLLUULLLULLUDLRDLDURRURDLDLRDUULDRLLRRLDUDDUULULR";

// for 1 - 9, map to each possible new position under U,D,L,R
int next[36] = {1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6, 4,5,6,7,8,9,7,8,9, 1,1,2,4,4,5,7,7,8, 2,3,3,5,6,6,8,8,9,};
int pos = 0;
int key = 5;
int pressit = 0;

int main()
{
    printf("Key: ");
    while (input[pos]!='\0') {
        char dir = input[pos++];
        int move = dir=='U' ? 0 : dir=='D' ? 1 : dir=='L' ? 2 : dir=='R' ? 3 : -1;
        key = next[9*move+key-1];
        while (input[pos] && (input[pos]=='\r' || input[pos]=='\n' || input[pos]==' ')) pressit=1,pos++;
        if (pressit) pressit=0, printf("%d",key);
    }
    printf("%d\n",key);
}
```

The output is:

```
C:\Workarea\AdventOfCode>day02.exe
Key: 84452
C:\Workarea\AdventOfCode>
```

Part 2 is similar, but the keypad is 'not what you had imagined'!

As before, we can utilize a simple state machine, but we map the keypad 1-13 over the possible moves on the keypad up, down, left and right.

```
// http://adventofcode.com/2016/day/2
//
// "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat" to setup
// cl day01.c to compile
// day01.exe to run

// given a string to be read as moves on a telephone keypad
// identify the code for the bathroom at Easter Bunny HQ section
// starting from the '5'
// 1 2 3
// 4 5 6
// 7 8 9

// part 2 ... unfortunately the keypad is not what you imagined:
//     1
//   2 3 4
// 5 6 7 8 9
//   A B C
//     D

// test input -> 5DB3
//char * input = "ULL RRDDD LURDL UUUUD";

char * input = "DLDRDDDLULDRRLUDDLDUURDRDUULDRDDRRLDLLUUDDLLRLRDRUURLUDURDDRURLUDDUULUURLLRRRRUDULUDLULLUURRLLRRURRUDUUURRLUUUDURDLLLDULDRLRDDDUDDUURLRRRURULLUDDUULDRRRDDLRLUDDRRDLRDURLRURUDDUULDDUUDDURRLUURRULRRLDLULLRLRUULDUDDLLLRDDULRUDURRDUUDUUDDUULULURDLUDRURDLUUDRDUURDDDRDRLDLDRURRLLRURURLLULLRRUULRRRRDLDULDDLRRRULRURRDURUDUUULDUUDRLDDLDUDDRULLUDUULRRRDRRDRDULDLURDDURLRUDLURLUDDDRLLURUUUUUUURUULDUUDDRLULRUDURRDLDUULLRLULLURDDDDDLRRDLRLLDDUDRRRDDURDLRRUDDUDLRRRDDURULRURRRLDRDUDLD LRRDUDUUUDRRURRDUUULULUDDLLDRRRUDDUULRRDRUDRLLRLRULRRDUUDRLDURUDLLLDRRDLRLUUDRUDRRRUDRRRULDRRLLRDDDLLRDDRULRLLRUDRLLLULDLDDRDRUUUUUULURLLRUDRDRLLULLRUUURRDRULULUDLDURRUUDURLLUDRDLDDULUDLRDDRLRLURULDRURRRRURRDDUDRULUUUDDDRULRULDLLURUUULRDDLRUURLRLDLUULLURDRDDDUDDDRLDRDLLDRDDDDURLUUULDDRURULUDDURDRDRLULDULURDUURDRLLUUUULRULUUDRLLDDRRURUURLDLLRRRDLRURDDLDLDRLRRDLDURULDDLULRRRUUDLRDUURDURLURDDLDLRURLLLDRDULDDRUDDULDDRRLDLRDRDLDUUDLUULRLUDUUDUUUULDURULRRUDULURLRLDRLULLLDUDLLLRUDURDDDURLDDLRLRRDLUDLDDDDLULDRLDUUULDRRDDLRUULDLULUUURUDDRLDDDULRUDRURUURUUURRULRURDURLLRLLUULUULURDRLLUDDLU LLDURDUDRLURUDRLRLUDDRRURDULULDDUDUULRRLRLRRDRDRDURRLRLURRLRUDULLUULLURUDDRLDDDRURLUUDLDURRDURDDLUULRDURRUUURLRRURRDRDRDURRRLULLDRUDLRUDURDRDDLLULLULRRUDULDDRDRRDLLLDLURLRDRDLUDDRLDDLDRULDURLLRLDRDLUDDDDLDUUDRLLRRRRLDDRRLRLURLLRLLUULLDUUDLRDRRRDRDLLDULLDRLDDUDRDDRURRDDLRDLRRUUDRRRRDURUULDRDDURLURRRRURRDRRULULURULUUUDRRRLDLLLDDRULRUDDURDRLDDRDLULLLRURUDRLRDDLDLRRRUURDURLDURRUUDDLRDRUUUURDLRLULRUUDRLDLULLULUURURDULUDUDRRRLLRLURLLDLRRURURRUDLUDDDDRDUDUDUUUULLDRDLLLLUUUUDRLRLUDURLLUDRUUDLLURUULDDDDULUUURLLDL DLULLRDLRRLLLDLRRURRDRURDRUUULDDRLURURRDLRRULUUDDRLRRLDULRRUUDUULDDDUDLLDLURDRLLULLUUULLDURDRRRDDLRDUDRRRLRLDRRLRLULDDUDURRRLDLRULDULDDUDDRULDLDRDRDDRUDRUDURRRRUUDUDRLDURLDLRRUURRDDUDLLDUDRRURRLRRRRRLDUDDRLLLURUDRRUDRLRDUDUUUUUDURULLDUUDLRUUULDUUURURLUUDULDURUDDDLRRRDDRRDLRULLLRDDRLRLUULDUUULLLLDLRURLRRDURRLDLLLDURDLLUDDDLLDDURDDULURDRRRDDDLDDURRULUUDDLULLURULUULDLDDLUDRURURULUDDULRDRLDRRRUUUURUULDRLRRURRLULULURLLDRLRLURULRDDDULRDDLUR RURRULLRRDLDUDDRRULUDLURLRRDDRDULLLUUDDDRDDRRULLLDRLRUULRRUDLDLLLRLLULDRLDDDLLDDULLDRLULUUUURRRLLDRLDLDLDDLUDULRDDLLRLLLULLUDDRDDUUUUDLDLRRDDRDLUDURRUURUURDULLLLLULRRLDRLRDLUURDUUDLDRURURLLDRRRLLLLRDLDURRLRRLLRUUDDUULLRLUDLRRRRRURUDDURULURRUULRDDULUUDUUDDRDDDDDUUUDDDRRLDDRRDDUUULDURLDULURDRDLLURDULRUDRUULUULLRRRRLRUUDDUDLDURURLRRRULRDRRUDDRDDRLRRRLRURRRUULULLLUULLLULLUDLRDLDURRURDLDLRDUULDRLLRRLDUDDUULULR";

// for 1 - 13, map to each possible new position under U,D,L,R
int next[52] = {1, 2,1,4, 5,2,3,4,9,    6,7,8,    11,
                3, 6,7,8, 5,10,11,12,9, 10,13,12, 13,
                1, 2,2,3, 5,5,6,7,8,    10,10,11, 13,
                1, 3,4,4, 6,7,8,9,9,    11,12,12, 13,};
int pos = 0;
int key = 5;
int pressit = 0;
char out[] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D'};

int main()
{
    printf("Key: ");
    while (input[pos]!='\0') {
        char dir = input[pos++];
        int move = dir=='U' ? 0 : dir=='D' ? 1 : dir=='L' ? 2 : dir=='R' ? 3 : -1;
        key = next[13*move+key-1];
        while (input[pos] && (input[pos]=='\r' || input[pos]=='\n' || input[pos]==' ')) pressit=1,pos++;
        if (pressit) pressit=0, printf("%c",out[key-1]);
    }
    printf("%c\n",out[key-1]);
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Workarea\AdventOfCode>day02-2.exe
Key: D65C3
C:\Workarea\AdventOfCode>
```

Comment: And that output was expected or what? If not, what would have been expected?

Comment: Yes, it's correct!